# Change font size

Tags: fontsize

I trying to change the size of the eurm font in a paper by defining it like this:

```
\font\twelveeurm=eurm12 \font\eleveneurm=eurm11 \font\teneurm=eurm10 \font\nineeurm=eurm9 
\font\eighteurm=eurm8 \font\seveneurm=eurm7 \font\fiveeurm=eurm5 \newfam\eurmfam
\textfont\eurmfam=\teneurm \scriptfont\eurmfam=\nineeurm \scriptscriptfont\eurmfam=\fiveeurm
\def\eurm#1{{\fam\eurmfam\relax#1}}
```

I am using the packages `euler`, `amsmath`, `amsthm`, `amssymb`, `showlabels` in the preamble. One character has been defined:

```
\def\g{\text{{\twelveeurm g}}}
```

I keep getting these error messages:

```
\twelveeurm=eurm12 not loadable: Bad metric (TFM) file.
```

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font, so I will ignore the font specification; and a similar message with `\eleveneurm`.  My apologies for the log post

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't use Plain TeX font definitions in LaTeX. Moreover there are no such font as `eurm12` and `eurm11`. Can you tell what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Are you using LaTeX?

Comment: This is the original definition:  \def\g{\text{{\teneurm g}}} I am trying to force the character to 12pt, by defining as \def\g{\text{{\twelveeurm g}}}.  This does not work.

Comment: I am using LaTex.

Answer (score 3):

you're overriding the built-in font control for euler.  euler, all by itself, changes size
along with its surroundings, so specifying the size in ordinary latex terms should suffice.

this definition should produce what you want:

```
\def\g{\text{\Large $g$}}
```

(this assumes that `\Large` is equivalent to `12pt` in the document class you are using.)

**edit:** here is an example.  the "open g" shape, while characteristic of many italic
fonts, is the shape chosen for euler to emulate handwriting.

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{euler}
\def\g{\text{\Large $g$}}
\begin{document}
Here we want a large Euler ``g'': $\g$.

\medskip
Some more math: $a + b = c$.

In the absence of other adjustments, the \texttt{euler}
package changes all math letters to upright cursive.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This changed the g to 12pt, but also changes it to  italics, not roman.  Thank you.

Comment: i don't understand your statement that the "g" is changed to italics.  the "open g" is the (only) shape provided in the `eurm` font.  i've added an example.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I used:  \def\g{\text{\normalsize $g$}} and that increased the size of the font.